# Devise's strong parameter isn't whitelisting a field input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

It seems that the custom input field I added isn't being whitelisted(showing blank validation error on submit).

Here's the controller:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
  end
end
```

It's basically a copy-past from Devise's documentation, yet it's not working at all(i.e., not whitelisting my custom input field).

UPDATE:
Here's the form:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">

    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :password %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "accounts/shared/links" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:name) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope it will help you and solve your issue.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) } #here you can permit custom fields. 
  end

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

Comment: post your devise registration form

Comment: Your form code is fine so i suggest you take a new project and follow the steps on https://github.com/plataformatec/devise] and try to add your custom fields.

Comment: Post your user model, devise migration and routes file.

Comment: Yeah - the User model will help us understand your Devise install; if it's a validation error, it's most likely something to do with a allow_blank or something like that.